# User Authentication on Twitter using TweetInvi

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I would like to post tweets on another user account without getting the pincode everytime I post on behalf of the user. I'm using TweetInvi library and C#. How do I integrate getting the pincode for the first time and getting the necessary API keys in order for next time, I would no longer need to get the pincode once the user authorize me to tweet on their behalf. An example of code would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance who could help me on this.